# Python Print function adding unwanted new line

Tags: python, string, data-processing

I have a script that reads a file. The file contains lines of text data, each line corresponds to a player and each attribute of a player is separated by a tab.

My script breaks apart the line into an array for each player, then simply reconstructs the data into a string that I want to save to a separate file, so that each individual line in the new file corresponds to a player:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def main():
    exampleDataFile = open("exampleData.txt", "r")
    dataStorageFile = open("playerStrings.txt", "w+")

for line in exampleDataFile:
    modifiedLine = line.replace('“','"').replace('”','"')
    listOfComponents = modifiedLine.split("\t")
    uid = listOfComponents[0]
    gamerID = listOfComponents[1]
    userPhoneNumber = listOfComponents[2]
    _geoloc = listOfComponents[3]
    allocatedTimes = listOfComponents[4]
    clanName = listOfComponents[5]

    gamerString = ('let ' + uid + ' = player(gamerID: "' + gamerID + '", userPhoneNumber: "' + userPhoneNumber + '", _geoloc: makeCoordinates(points: (' + _geoloc + ")), allocatedTimes: makeallocatedTimes(" + allocatedTimes + '), clanName: "' + clanName + '")\n')
    print (gamerString)
    dataStorageFile.write(gamerString)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I check the logs and also the file that the output was saved to, the first output is printed/saved to a single line, which is exactly what i want. However, all subsequent lines are broken off at the final `'")\n'`. What I get is this:

```
let r2 = player(gamerID: "TE2", userPhoneNumber: "3456106340", _geoloc: makeCoordinates(points: (51.563601,  -0.118769)), allocatedTimes: makeallocatedTimes(mon:("0700","2300"),tue:("0700","2300"),wed:("0700","2300"),thu:("0700","2300"),fri:("0700","2300"),sat:("0700","2300"),sun:("0700","2300")), clanName: "Tesco
")
```

Notice how the `")` is on a separate line. This is not what I want, I want it like this:

```
let r2 = player(gamerID: "TE2", userPhoneNumber: "3456106340", _geoloc: makeCoordinates(points: (51.563601,  -0.118769)), allocatedTimes: makeallocatedTimes(mon:("0700","2300"),tue:("0700","2300"),wed:("0700","2300"),thu:("0700","2300"),fri:("0700","2300"),sat:("0700","2300"),sun:("0700","2300")), clanName: "Tesco")
```

I have tried printing out very long strings and they all print/save to a single line for each print, but for some reason when I print/save the gamer output, I get the `")` on a separate line and I'm not sure why? Thanks!

Comment: You're aware that you have  `\n` at the end, which results in a new line? And if you want to print exactly what's given to print, simply do `print("something", end="")`. But most likely, your issue is that one of your variables contains a `\n` in the data. so do `listOfComponents[4].strip()` to clear those out.

Comment: can you share that line from file...

Comment: @Torxed Thanks for the quick response, I am aware that I have `\n` at the end, however you will notice that this is after the `")`. That being said, adding `.strip()` to the end of each `listOfComponents[x]` has worked, so thank you very much! If you post this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Glad it worked, @Slam beat me to the punch so accept that answer if it solves it the way you want it to ^^ Just happy it works! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python does *not* strips newline characters at the end of the line when reading file. That means that file with content like

```
row1,value1
row2,value2
```

Will be read as two strings, containing `"row1,value1\n"` and `" row2,value2\n"`.

Make something like `modifiedLine = line.strip('\n')` as part of cleaning/preprocessing.